# Python os.walk, way to save state?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a need to iterate over all files on a file server, and I would like to be able to stop the process and resume it at a later time, anywhere in the file tree. Can this be done with os.walk, or does this need to be implemented from scratch?

Edit: Ideally I would like the solution to be persistent, so the script can stop and pick back up later.

Comment: Is the directory structure not expected to change between walks?

Comment: It might change, but I don't mind missing newly created/deleted files. I can run it again at a later time to pick up any missed files.

Comment: You want to save state within a single run, or you want to be able to persist it to disk (or database or whatever) so you can quit and relaunch and pick the walk back up?

Comment: I'm envisioning some kind of persistence. The script occasionally crashes due to some rare case I hadn't considered, or due to an unstable network connection.

Comment: Before we get too fancy… unless you need to prune the tree dynamically, or the tree is going to be absolutely gigantic and pre-walking it would take too long/too much storage, you can always just persist `list(w)`. Is that acceptable for your use case?

Comment: There are about 3 million files. Do you think that's too many?

Comment: Well, that depends on your use case. You might want to just try doing the `list` thing and stashing it (with `pickle`, or `csv`, or whatever seems appropriate) and see how much time and space it takes.

Answer (score 7):

`os.walk` is a perfectly normal generator function, which means you can call it, save the resulting generator, and iterate it at your leisure. For example:

```
w = os.walk(root)

for root, dirs, files in w:
   if root == 'foo':
       break
   else:
       # usual stuff

print('Hey, we found foo')

for root, dirs, files in w:
    # usual stuff
```

You can even `w` to a function, or return it from one, or use it as an iterator with your favorite `itertools` function, etc.

---

The one big thing you *can't* do with it is pickle it. So, if you want to persist it to disk (or to a database) so you can quit the program and resume where you left off, or send it off to a child process to be finished, or whatever, you can't do that.

If you can afford to just do the whole walk in advance instead of doing it lazily (i.e., you don't need to prune the walk dynamically, and the time and storage to do the walk itself is dwarfed by the time and storage needed for your real work), you can just persist `list(w)`. Then, you just need to keep track of that list, and the index you've gotten to so far (or just persist `wlist[index:]` instead of `wlist` and `index`). But for some use cases, that's not acceptable.

Fortunately, `walk` implemented in pure Python, and it's pretty simple, so you can copy the code from [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/os.py#l337) and modify it to make the state persistable. The problem is that the state is partly implicit, through the magic of `yield`, so you have to either turn the generator inside-out, or convert it to an equivalent purely-iterative solution. Here's a start:

```
class Walk(object):
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.queue = [top]
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        top = self.queue.pop(0)
        names = os.listdir(top)
        dirs, nondirs = [], []
        for name in names:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(top, name)):
                dirs.append(name)
            else:
                nondirs.append(name)
        self.queue.extend(os.path.join(top, dir) for dir in dirs)
        return top, dirs, nondirs
```

This doesn't handle any of the optional arguments. `followlinks=False` and `onerror` are trivial. Handling the dynamic pruning for `topdown=True` is not much trickier (just stash `top` and `dirs`, and enqueue the children at the start of the next call instead of the end of this one). Doing `topdown=False` would be a little more painful, but still not *too* bad (you can create an explicit stack of states for the standard recursive-to-iterative transition, or keep an extra deque around, or just create, stash, and iterate a list of new `Walk` objects). If you don't need them, don't bother adding them.

I believe this will `pickle` with no changes. (If not, it's either a trivial `__getstate__` or a near-trivial `__reduce__` away from working.) If you're using a different persistence mechanism, really, all you need to persist is that this is a `Walk` object whose `queue` is `self.queue` (which is just a list of strings), so that should be easy.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for some sort of persistence.

Answer (score 0):

In the end for my solution to this same problem, I gutted the innards of python's os.walk, and put some wrappers around before processing a directory and afterwards.

The wrappers talk to an sqlite database, and recall which directories they've already seen. This lets it prune the tree as aggressively as it can for work already done.

NB: For my use case, reprocessing files in a given directory wasn't a problem, if you need to strictly re-enter an os.walk exactly where you left off, then you'll need to track the files too -- don't forget that once you've finished with a directory you can purge the file information to save on database size.

```py
import os
import sys
import sqlite3
class WalkPersister():
    def __init__(self, db_filename, onerror=None, followlinks=False):
        self._db_filename = db_filename
        self._onerror = onerror
        self._followlinks = followlinks

        
    def __enter__(self):
        self._con = sqlite3.connect(self._db_filename)
        self._con.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS walk_persistence (
            path text PRIMARY KEY,
            files int,
            total_sub_files int
        )
        ''')
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        self._con.commit()
        
    def walk(self, top, onerror=None, followlinks=False):
        # Almost entirely from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/os.py#L344
        if not self._pre_visit(top):
            return

        dirs = []
        nondirs = []
        walk_dirs = []

        try:
            scandir_it = os.scandir(top)
        except OSError as error:
            if onerror is not None:
                onerror(error)
            return

        with scandir_it:
            while True:
                try:
                    try:
                        entry = next(scandir_it)
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
                except OSError as error:
                    if onerror is not None:
                        onerror(error)
                    return

                try:
                    is_dir = entry.is_dir()
                except OSError:
                    # If is_dir() raises an OSError, consider that the entry is not
                    # a directory, same behaviour than os.path.isdir().
                    is_dir = False

                if is_dir:
                    dirs.append(entry.name)
                else:
                    nondirs.append(entry.name)

        yield top, dirs, nondirs

        # Recurse into sub-directories
        islink, join = os.path.islink, os.path.join
        for dirname in dirs:
            new_path = join(top, dirname)
            if followlinks or not islink(new_path):
                yield from self.walk(new_path, onerror, followlinks)

        self._post_visit(top, dirs, nondirs)
        
        
    def _pre_visit(self, path):
        cursor = self._con.execute('''
        SELECT
            path
        FROM
            walk_persistence
        WHERE
            path = ?
        ''', (path, ))
        return cursor.fetchone() is None
    
    def _post_visit(self, path, dirs, nondirs):
        cursor = self._con.execute('''
        SELECT
            files
        FROM
            walk_persistence
        WHERE
            path LIKE ? || '%'
        ''', (path, ))
        sub_files = sum((i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall())) + len(nondirs)
        self._con.execute('''
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 
            walk_persistence
        VALUES (
            ?, ?, ?
        )
        ''', (path, len(nondirs), sub_files))
```

Usage:

```py
import pathlib
import random
with WalkPersister('/home/appuser/walk.db') as walker:
    for src_dname, sdirs, files in walker.walk('/data/'):
        src_dname = pathlib.Path(src_dname)
        for file in files:
            filepath = src_dname/file
            print(filepath)
            if random.randint(0, 5000) == 13: raise ValueError('Demo Exception')
```